Moving the cursor on a link changes the text layout in the Stacks Editor
Moving the cursor on a link changes the text layout in the Stacks Editor. Example:

Tested with Chrome + Windows 10.

The rich text editor is clearly in alpha rather than beta and I'd recommend anyone just not use it.
